# How to clear images from memory - after removing from DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, memory-management

I have javascript which creates dozens of `<div>` elements loading images with `background-image:url(http://differentDomain.com/someImage.jpg)`

They are all appended into of `<div id = "container">`

After The images are displayed on screen, and a css animation is completed, I remove container with:

```
var c = document.getElementById('container')
c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
```

After removing that I get a new set of images, create a new container and start the process again.

Issue is - after removing the container, page does not clear the memory, and continues to swell in memory indefinetly - in the image, the memory has swollen after a few iterations.
[image: memory is not cleared]

**Is there a more optimal way to remove from DOM? 
Could this be connected to using a css animation on images?**

Comment: I don't really think that's the cause but do you keep any reference to the container or its content, or are the removed nodes sent to garbage collection?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil It seems that I don't have any reference left to the object, but I am finding it hard to make sure

Comment: @JacqueGoupil After removing all references, image cache stays remains low, but the memory column still stays extremely high and continues to grow each iteration

Comment: Mm, then I have no clue. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data shows, the images are in the browser cache and the DOM does not contain images. That's not what it does. Probably you implement caching on your web site. The only way to remove those from memory is to just not serve the images as cachable in the first place and let the browser remove them on its own which the browser and, possibly, the OS will do.

In the comments, @Jacque brings up an interesting point about references which might be an issue to think about.

Comment: It seems this behavior is as planned. Image cache on my system stays in memory regardless of DOM actions.